# How do I enable the Google Sheets API from the Firebase console?

Tags: firebase, google-sheets-api

When trying to enable the Google Sheets API, Google asks me to create new/choose an app. When I choose an app that I already have in Firebase it says that I have to use the Firebase console to manage Google Services for this project. I have looked for ways to enable the sheets API from the console but haven't found a way to get to what I am looking for.

Comment: is this sheets api or apps-script?

Comment: its the sheets api